# Is there a way to re-provision an iPhone IPA file without re-compiling or using XCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, mobile, ios-provisioning

We've created an iPhone application and provisioned the application for deployment. In XCode we've used the build & archive tool to create an IPA file that can be used for installation.  When new devices are added to the profile we would like to re-provision the IPA without recompiling or re-exporting the app from XCode.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm definitely interested in this as well.  I have to keep a copy of my old builds for when I add new testers while I'm mid-version.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the detail tabs of the XCode Build Results window after your Ad Hoc build, you will notice that the last few steps include running the ProcessProductPackaging and CodeSign utilities.

If you copy those command lines (and the intervening and following steps, if any), you could manually run these commands (or from a shell script), substituting the newer mobileprovision file in the appropriate place, to create a reprovisioned ipa file without a recompile.